# Sorting a list by the last character

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a program that would order a list by the last character.

```
["Apple", "Mellon", "Banana"]
```

This is my list and I need to arrange them such that it becomes.

```
["Banana", "Apple", "Mellon"]
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 10):

You can sort using a function, here we use the lambda function which looks at the last index of the strings inside of your list.

```
lst = ["Apple", "Mellon", "Banana"]
sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[-1])
```

> ['Banana', 'Apple', 'Mellon']

---

Without making a copy of the list you can apply the `.sort()`. This is a more memory efficient method.

```
lst.sort(key=lambda x: x[-1])
print(lst)
```

> ['Banana', 'Apple', 'Mellon']

Comment: `sorted(lst)` creates a new list. `lst.sort()` sorts the existing, in-place. I believe OP wants the second flavor.

Comment: Or use `operator.itemgetter` with `itemgetter(-1)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sort` method by passing a `lambda` expression for `key` property.

This method does not *return* any value but it changes from the *original* list.

```
l = ["Apple", "Mellon", "Banana"]
l.sort(key = lambda item: item[-1])
```

Output

```
['Banana', 'Apple', 'Mellon']
```