# How to sort a vector of strings based on the last Character in R

Tags: r, string, sorting

I want to sort a vector of strings based on the last character in R.
Lets say I have m

```
m <- names(df)
m
[1] "test_1_p" "test_2_n" "test_3_p" "test_4_p" "test_5_n"
```

For reproduciblity:

```
m <- c("test_1_p","test_2_n","test_3_p","test_4_p","test_5_n")
```

Now my Desired output would be

```
[1] "test_2_n" "test_5_n" "test_1_p" "test_3_p" "test_4_p"
```

I tried to work with `strsplit`, but couldn't get it to work

```
r = strsplit(m,"_")
sorting_df = data.frame(r)
sort(sorting_df[3,])
```

I belief there has to be a fairly simple solution to that comparable to python where one could easily do it [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50367558/7318488)

```
lst = ["test_1_p","test_2_n","test_3_p","test_4_p","test_5_n"]
sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[-1])
```

**Edit** All provided Solutions work thank you very much. Just accepted the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the last part from the string and use it's `order` to subset the string.

```
m[order(sub('.*_', '', m))]
#[1] "test_2_n" "test_5_n" "test_1_p" "test_3_p" "test_4_p"
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
m[order(substr(m,nchar(m),nchar(m)))]
[1] "test_2_n" "test_5_n" "test_1_p" "test_3_p" "test_4_p"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `funprog::sort_by`:

```
lastChar <- function(str){
  substr(str, nchar(str), nchar(str))
}
library(funprog)
sort_by(m, lastChar)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `stri_extract_last`

```
library(stringi)
m[order(stri_extract_last(m, regex = "\\w"))]
#[1] "test_2_n" "test_5_n" "test_1_p" "test_3_p" "test_4_p"
```